# Найти значение через регулярку php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строки:

```
10% лен, 30% хлопок; 120м/50г
100м/70г; 45% холща, 20% эластан 
70г 10м 100% хлопок
```

Нужно вычленить метраж и вес, разложив в разные строки (т.е. получить "100м", затем "50г" и другие значения)

В столь хаотично представленных данных, не могу понять, как их можно выбрать. По шаблону "(любое число)м" и "(любое число)г"? Но не получается такое выражение составить правильно

Так получается получить только цифры:

```
$str = "70г 10м 100% хлопок";
$str = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $str);
```

Comment: Только м и г из каждой строки?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin ну да. Как еще получить значения метража и веса не вижу вариантов. Остальные данные игнорируем

Comment: как по мне решение должно быть с именованными подмасками, чтобы не важно было, в каком порядке данные, и не зависеть от номера группы

Comment: Ответ уже дан, но на будущее советую `https://regex101.com/` удобный сервис для проверки регулярных выражений.

Comment: Им и пользуюсь) Но тут он подвел - все работало без флага unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/\d+[мг]/u", $text, $out);
print_r($out[0]);
```

Comment: действительно, поправил

Comment: @Nikita Umnov находит, только работает не совсем точно. Почему то находит и такие значения "30к 70м" , хотя прописано [гм] http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db9345d3e4107ad5f44774e5f48e1b5d4b837c6c

Comment: @Amsterdam поправил, нужен флаг для работы с unicode

Comment: @Nikita Umnov здОрово, большое спасибо! Решение подходящее